# Full Clang warning list with descriptions

Tags: clang, warnings

I need to get full Clang warnings list. With Descriptions. For iOS.
I've seen just a list of warnings here
[Clang Warnings](http://www.xs-labs.com/en/blog/2012/01/10/warning-flags-clang/)

But there is no description.
Is there any place where i can get full list of Clang warnings with the description?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**(Note: This answer is now outdated.)**

There's a neat project that shows the flags alongside their warning messages:

https://github.com/NSHipster/fuckingclangwarnings.com

While these are not comprehensive explanations in all cases, it is very helpful, especially when you want to switch off specific warnings.

The project hasn't been updated in a while and is probably missing a few new warnings. You could also dive into Clang's source code. I haven't worked with it in a while, but I can tell you where to start:

1. Clone the [Clang repository](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#checkout)
2. Browse to [`/include/clang/Basic/Diagnostic.td`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Basic/Diagnostic.td). This file includes a couple of other `.td` files which contain the various warnings, though I'm not sure if all of them are publicly available, and I think their external names are prefixed, depending on their category. I suggest searching for a known warning (or its description) to solve the puzzle.
3. Another interesting file is [`/include/clang/Driver/Options.td`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Driver/Options.td), which includes the texts you get using the `help` command, if I recall correctly.

Comment: http://fuckingclangwarnings.com and http://clangwarnings.com are now defunct, but https://github.com/NSHipster/clangwarnings.com is still active (altho archived).  .. Wait, no it isn't, because it now just redirects to the clang docs.

Answer (score 19):

I realize this is an old question, but a complete list of warnings, along with the text printed for each one, can be found in the [Clang Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html).

Comment: I’m not sure what’s there counts as much of a description, e.g. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wexit-time-destructors pretty much repeats the name of the flag, rather than describing what the criterion for the warning is.  I must reluctantly agree with Enji (below) that "the source code is the documentation," or at least the closest thing to documentation that the maintainers take seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The [current] accepted answer is correct. clang/clang++'s documentation up on the website doesn't necessarily reflect the supported options in the code. As the old phrase goes, "the source code is the documentation" :/..

One thing that will help with finding options is grepping the source code for `DiagGroup`. For example, the following demonstrates an attempt at grepping for `sign-compare`, aka `-Wsign-compare`, using a pared down clang 7.0.1 source checkout:

```
$ grep --include \*.td -r sign-compare . | grep DiagGroup
tools/clang/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td:def SignCompare : DiagGroup<"sign-compare">;
```